# how to put &&var&i into if condition

Tags: if-statement, macros, sas

```
/*create macro variables*/
    PROC SQL NOPRINT;
    SELECT RESTRICTIONS
    INTO :RESTRI1 - :RESTRI35 
    FROM SASDATA.RESTRICTIONLIST; 
    QUIT;
    %PUT &RESTRI2;

/*the resolved value is: */
gender = 'M' and state = 'CA'
```

I want to create a data set `sasdata.newlist&i` when the ith restriction
 is `&&restri&i` (eg: `gender = 'M'` and `state = 'CA'`).
I only want the observations which meet the restriction `&&restri&I*` in this new created dataset

***While the sasdata.newlist2 contains all data in sasdata.oldlist, the if condition doesn't work. Anybody can help me to solve this problem?***

```
%Macro testing(I);
 data sasdata.newlist&i;
 set sasdata.oldlist;
 %if &&restri&i %then; 
 run;
%mend testing;
%testing(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not resolving the macro variables in the proper context.   When applying the restriction code, resolve it so it can be compiled (data step-wise) as part of the DATA step.

```
%Macro testing(I);
 data sasdata.newlist&i;
 set sasdata.oldlist;

 /* %if &&restri&i %then;  NO-no-no, incorrect context */

 * apply ith restriction as a sub-setting IF statement;
 if &&restri&i;

 run;
%mend testing;
%testing(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's hard to tell when to use macro statement, when not.

for example: Do I need to put % in the if -then-else statement and do while statement in code below? By the way, can I use "Do i = 1 to n while (condition)" statement here like this?

```
%MACRO FUNDSOURCE(I);
DATA SASDATA.STUDENT&I; 
SET SASDATA.STUDENTLIST 
DO M = 1 TO 310  WHILE(&&BUDG&I > 0); /*loop through all observations_ALL 
      STUDENTS*/
 IF &&BUDG&I LE 3000- FA_TOT1  THEN do;
      DISBURSE = &&BUDG&I;
      FA_TOT1+DISBURE;
     &&BUDG&I - DISBURSE;
 end;
 ELSE IF &&BUDG&I GT (3000- FA_TOT1)  THEN DO;
    DISBURSE = 3000-FA_TOT1;
    FA_TOT1+DISBURSE;
    &&BUDG&I - DISBURSE;
 END;
 END;
IF _n_ > M THEN DELETE; /*if budget are all gone, delete other observations, 
       keep observations only for the student who get funds*/
RUN;
%MEND FUNDSOURCE;
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a follow-up question.  You could either edit your original question to have this example, or ask as a separate question.